# Decorate restify render

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, decorator, restify

I am trying to decorate render function in restify's router with this code...

decorate.js

```
module.exports = function (server) {
    return function (req, res, next) {
        function newRender(orig) {
            return function(path, params, query) {
                return "http://localhost:3000" + orig(path, params, query);
            }
        }
    server.router.render = newRender(server.router.render);
    next();
    }
}
```

and in my server.js

```
var restify = require("restify");
var decorate = require("./decorate");
var server = restify.createServer();

server.pre(decorate(server));

server.get({name: "get_user", path: "/users/:id"}, function(req, res){
    res.send(req.params.id);
});

server.get("/decorate", function(req, res){
    res.send({data: server.router.render("get_user", {id: 2})});
});


server.listen(3000);
```

but I only get this error. Please help.
{"code":"InternalError","message":"Cannot read property 'get_user' of undefined"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the original `render` method with global `this` as context. Just bind the `server.router` as context when passing it:

```
original_render = server.router.render;

function decorate(){
...
server.router.render = newRender(original_render.bind(server.router));
...
}
```

**Update**: You keep the reference of original render method outside the middleware function. Otherwise there will be a stack of newRender calls with increasing requests.